# Serialize class into soap1.2 format string

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I would like to serialize Model class object into soap1.2 format string.

```
public class Model
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public int age{get;set;}
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Model xmlns="http://modelws/">
      <name>Kevin</name>
      <age>25</age>
    </Model>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: what is the problem in your serialization code? it seems to be a very basic requirement and can be done with the help of one or two google searching.

Comment: i wanted to create custom message format instead of adding webservice. I don't think it is as 'basic' as you think.